# How to print to screen all array elements stored in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

Good Morning,
I'm new in javascript and I'm having trouble getting a full array from local storage.
I made this code, but it only prints on screen the data stored in the last element of the array, and I intended to print on screen the data of all elements of the array. Someone can help me? 
I can't use jquery

```js
var preco_final=0; // preço total -> adiciona o preco de todos os bilhetes comprados
function mostrar(){  

    var carrinho=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('carrinho-compras'));
    for(i=0;i<carrinho.length;i++)
    {    

        //guarda em variáveis os dados que estão no localstorage
        var tipo_bilhete_carrinho= "tipo de bilhete: " +carrinho[i].tipo_de_bilhete;
        var dias_carrinho="dias: "+carrinho[i].dias;
        var nome_carrinho="nome: "+carrinho[i].nome_t;
        var nadultos_carrinho="númeor de adultos: "+carrinho[i].numero_adultos;
        var ncriancas_carrinho="número de crianças: "+carrinho[i].numero_criancas;
        var preco_carrinho="preço do bilhete: "+carrinho[i].preco_total; // preço do bilhete em causa
        preco_final +=carrinho[i].preco_total; // preço total -> adiciona o preco de todos os bilhetes comprados
       
        // Guarda todas as variáveis num array e converte numa lista pela função map
        var compra=[tipo_bilhete_carrinho,dias_carrinho,nome_carrinho,nadultos_carrinho,ncriancas_carrinho,preco_carrinho];
        ReactDOM.render(React.createElement("ul", {id:"lista_compras"},
            compra.map( (compra) => React.createElement("li", null, compra)),React.createElement("hr",null,"")),document.getElementsByClassName("itens")[0]);
        //hr tag que define mudança temática -> adiciona uma linha  
    }
    document.getElementById('preco_total').innerHTML= "Preço total: "+preco_final;
}

function apagar(){
    localStorage.removeItem('carrinho-compras'); //apaga o carrinho de compras
    document.getElementsByClassName('itens')[0].innerHTML="";// apaga o conteudo da div, de modo a não mostrar nada no ecrã
    document.getElementById('preco_total').innerHTML= ""; // apaga o conteudo da div do preço total
}
```

```css
body{ margin: 0;}

#lista_compras{
    list-style-type: none;     /* Remove as bolinhas dos elementos da lista */

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
    <head>  
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/carrinho_compras.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cabecalho_rodape.css">
        <script src="js/react.js"></script>
        <script src="js/react-dom.js"></script>
        <link rel="icon" type="images/jpg" href="imagens/logo.jpg"> 
        <title>Adventure Park - Bilheteira</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="mostrar()">
        <header id="cabecalho">    <!-- Cabeçalho / menu-->
            <a href="index.html" id="hyper_to_home">
            <div id="logo_name">
                <img id="logo" src="imagens/logo.png">
                <h3 id="nome_parque">Parque de diversões</h3>
            </div>
            </a>
            <div id="menudiv"></div>
            <picture><a href="carrinho_de_compras.html"><img id="carrinho_de_compras"src="imagens/Bilheteira/carrinho_compras.png" width="40px" height="35px" ></a> </picture>
        </header>

        <div class="itens" id="item"></div>
        <div id="preco_total"></div>
        <div id="btn_carrinho">
            <a href="bilheteira.html"><button>Continuar a comprar</button></a>
            <input type="reset" value="Apagar itens do carrinho" onclick="apagar()">
            
        </div>
        
        <footer id="rodape">      <!-- Rodapé -->
            <div id="data-hora">12/10/2019 23:59:10</div>
        </footer>
        <script src="js/menu.js"></script> <!-- script do menu -->
        <script src="js/carrinho_compras.js"></script>
        <script src="js/data_e_hora.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I store data in local storage:

```js
    // Pega a lista já registada, se não houver cria
    var carrinho_de_compras = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('carrinho-compras') || '[]');
    // Adiciona reserva
    carrinho_de_compras.push({
     tipo_de_bilhete: tipo_bilhete,
     dias: ndias,
     nome_t:nome,
     numero_adultos: nadultos,
     numero_criancas: ncriancas,
     preco_total: precoTotal
    });
    // Salva a lista alterada
    localStorage.setItem("carrinho-compras", JSON.stringify(carrinho_de_compras));
    alert("Bilhete adicionado ao carrino de compras");
```

Comment: can you post your sample data structure of carrinho-compras

Comment: Looks like you import React, so you might as well use it :) With frameworks like React, Angular or Vue, forget about manually setting `document.getElementById('preco_total').innerHTML`. It's their job to render the vue from the data you pass them.

Comment: @DILEEP THOMAS, already put

Answer (score 3):

You can go through the localStorage Array iteratively and then print each item individually like below

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
    console.log(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
}
```

Comment: I already did it. 'localStorage.getItem (localStorage.key (' shopping cart '));' 
But, How can I print in list with that code?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by printing in list :D . Maybe i didn't get what you mean can you please elaborate if no issues? Thanks.

Comment: I'm making a website, and it has more keys in local-storage (ex: "carrinho-compras" , "lista-reservas"), and with these codes prints all arrays, and I just want print "carrinho-compras".

Comment: localStorage.getItem ('carrinho-compras'); and then just console log this and it will print the whole array

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, but I already managed to solve the problem.`var lista[]; for(... ; ... ; ... ) /*passing local storage values*/  var compra=[tipo_bilhete_carrinho,dias_carrinho,nome_carrinho,nadultos_carrinho,ncriancas_carrinho,preco_carrinho];
        lista.push(React.createElement("ul", {id:"lista_compras"},
                 compra.map( (compra) => React.createElement("li", null, compra)),
                 React.createElement("hr",null,"")));
      }
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement("div", null, lista),
        document.getElementsByClassName("itens")[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add [Mustache.js](https://mustache.github.io/). Its a logicless* (*no ifs and elses, for cycles) engine to print templates, its super easy to implement. You can then print it into kind of a showtext component, exmp. [Showtext.jsx](https://gist.github.com/biswa8998/23dffbba0bde0a6002a6bd70f710ddb0), or if you require pop up, Alert type component, I would suggest [Reactstrap-modal](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/). If you will require logic templates, you can at any point add [Handlebars.js](https://handlebarsjs.com/) addon to Mustache.js, its fully compatible.